# The website can't be surfed when the dotnet run command executed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning c# by the guidance from Microsoft learning website.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/

I just followed the steps and executed the "dotnet run" command.
[image]

But when I surfed the website by the url:https://localhost:7145, it couldn't work like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a page at `/`? You can tell it's reaching the server because you're getting a server-generated status code (4040 response, not a "This site cannot be reached."

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be 404 response, not 4040.